# Ubuntu openconnect & RSA - Problem connecting VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, openconnect

I am trying to make a VPN connection in ubuntu from openconnect(Cisco Anyconnect). I could not make it through. I am getting below error. I tried from terminal but same error:

GUI:

[image]

Terminal:

[image]

Comment: I found a related bug [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=964329); have you tried with the `--no-xmlpost` argument?

Comment: Yea, tried that already.  --no-xmlpost did not help.